# Trying To Identify this Fish

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

[image: fish in aquarium]

My 4 year old fell in love with this fish at the aquarium.

I'm trying to find out what species it is so we can learn more about it.

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE. Please can u add the location and size of the fish. A clearer image would be appreciated.

Comment: You can also go to the aquarium's website (if it was commercial) and look up their fish.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a unicornfish (genus Naso), maybe *Naso vlamingii*, the Bignose Unicornfish. They're Acanthurids, related to surgeonfishes and tangs.

These are mainly found in Indo-Pacific ocean around the depth of 50 mts from surface. Coral reefs are their main habitat and destruction of coral reefs is their current biggest threat alongside trading by fisheries. A good source of information for this species is available [here](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/155120/0).

A copy of this fish.

[image: Naso vlamingii]

Picture credits: [UM Rosenstiel School](https://www.flickr.com/photos/rsmas/)

Comment: Yes, this is the right fish! There were other unicorn fish in the tank that actually had the "horn." I didn't realize there were other variations. Thank you so much!